# How can I have multiple embeds with buttons receiving user interactions at the same time? (Discord py)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

**edit(update):** thanks for the help, I'm just new to oop and cogs, so I have now made just one cog containing the quickpoll timer command, and regular class files for the Timer, NoMoreButtons, and QuickPollButtons classes. The only remaining thing I'm trying to understand is how to deal with the some_callback callback in the Timer class, because it needs to access the react_message(the one with the view), so that it can edit it to show the remaining time. **Will update more soon**

Hey all,
I'm brand new to stack overflow (first post) and also pretty new to discord py and coding in general. I made a /quickpoll cog for discord that contains an embeded message with two buttons attached (yes/no). One issue I've come across happens when I want to have two separate polls operating simultaneously. If I run /quickpoll twice to create two separate polls, the older poll's buttons are interacting with the newer poll. So no matter how many polls I create, the older poll's buttons will only apply to the newest poll.

Edit: How would you recommend going about solving this issue? Thanks in advance

**Background info on the code:**
Because I have the Timer class with a callback function that needs to access variables from the QuickPoll class (with the buttons), I made a few variables into QuickPoll class attributes (i.e. embededMsg, view, react_message).

Also, the NoMoreButtons class is just I used to make the buttons disappear once the poll timer ends.

**Here's my cog** (I deleted as much extraneous code as could. Apologies if its too long):

```
class QuickPoll(commands.Cog, discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.bot = bot
        self.value = None
        self.noCount = 0
        self.yesCount = 0
        self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted = []
        self.embededMsg = None
        self.view = None
        self.react_message = None

    @app_commands.command(name="quickpoll", description="Creates a yes/no poll for others to vote on")
    @app_commands.describe(question='example: Yes or no?')
    @app_commands.describe(duration='seconds')
    async def quickpoll(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, question: str, duration: str):
            await interaction.response.send_message(content="Command received", ephemeral=True, delete_after=0)
            QuickPoll.view = QuickPoll(bot=commands.Bot)
            pprint(QuickPoll.view.id)
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg = discord.Embed(type='rich', color=discord.Color.random(), title=question )
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_author(name=f'{interaction.user}\'s Poll')
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.add_field(name="Yes:", value=f"{QuickPoll.view.yesCount}", inline=True)
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.add_field(name='No:', value=f'{QuickPoll.view.noCount}', inline=True)
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_footer(text=f'Poll ID: {QuickPoll.view.id}')
            QuickPoll.view.react_message = await interaction.channel.send(content="", embed=QuickPoll.view.embededMsg, view=QuickPoll.view)
            timer1 = Timer(bot=commands.Bot, interval=5, first_immediately=True, timer_name="Timer 1", context={'count': (int(duration))}, callback=Timer.some_callback)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='1')
    async def button1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if f'{interaction.user.display_name}' not in self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted:
            print(f"Voted Yes: {interaction.user}")
            QuickPoll.view.yesCount = QuickPoll.view.yesCount + 1
            self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted += [f'{interaction.user.display_name}']
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_field_at(index=0,name="Yes:",value=f"{QuickPoll.view.yesCount}",inline=True)
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_field_at(index=3,name="Who has voted:",value=f"{', '.join(self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted)}",inline=False)  
            await QuickPoll.view.react_message.edit(content="", embed=QuickPoll.view.embededMsg, view=QuickPoll.view)
            await interaction.response.defer()
        else:
            await interaction.response.defer()
 
    @discord.ui.button(label="No", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id='2')
    async def button2(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button ):
        if f'{interaction.user.display_name}' not in self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted and QuickPoll.view.buttonIdJoin == QuickPoll.view.react_message.id:
            print(f"Voted No: {interaction.user}")
            QuickPoll.view.noCount = QuickPoll.view.noCount + 1
            self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted += [f'{interaction.user.display_name}']
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_field_at(index=1,name="No:",value=f"{QuickPoll.view.noCount}",inline=True)
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_field_at(index=3,name="Who has voted:",value=f"{', '.join(self.userNamesOfAlreadyVoted)}",inline=False)
            await QuickPoll.view.react_message.edit(content="", embed=QuickPoll.view.embededMsg, view=QuickPoll.view)
            await interaction.response.defer()
        else:
            await interaction.response.defer()

class Timer(QuickPoll, commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot, interval, first_immediately, timer_name, context, callback):
        super().__init__(bot) 
        self.bot = bot
        self._interval = interval
        self._first_immediately = first_immediately
        self._name = timer_name
        self._context = context
        self._callback = callback
        self._is_first_call = True
        self._ok = True
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())
        
    async def _job(self):
        try:
            while self._ok:
                if not self._is_first_call or not self._first_immediately:
                    await asyncio.sleep(self._interval) 
                await self._callback(self._name, self._context, self)
                self._is_first_call = False
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def cancel(self):
        self._ok = False
        self._task.cancel()

    async def some_callback(timer_name, context, timer):
        print('callback: ' + timer_name + ", count: ", context['count'])
        if context['count'] <= 0:
            print(f"Timer is up on the poll!")
            timer.cancel()
            QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.set_field_at(index=2,name="**Ends In:**",value="Ended!",inline=True)
            if QuickPoll.view.yesCount < QuickPoll.view.noCount:
                QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.add_field(name="Result: ", value=f"NO!!!!", inline=True)
                await QuickPoll.view.react_message.edit(content="", embed=QuickPoll.view.embededMsg, view=NoMoreButtons(bot=commands.Bot))
            if QuickPoll.view.yesCount > QuickPoll.view.noCount:
                QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.add_field(name="Result: ", value=f"YES!!!!", inline=True)
                await QuickPoll.view.react_message.edit(content="", embed=QuickPoll.view.embededMsg, view=NoMoreButtons(bot=commands.Bot))
            if QuickPoll.view.yesCount == QuickPoll.view.noCount:
                QuickPoll.view.embededMsg.add_field(name="Result: ", value=f"ITS A TIE!", inline=True)
                await QuickPoll.view.react_message.edit(content="", embed=QuickPoll.view.embededMsg, view=NoMoreButtons(bot=commands.Bot))
        context['count'] -= 5 

class NoMoreButtons(commands.Cog, discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.bot = bot
```

So far I've been trying to find some sort of ID or anything that the Bot's channel.send message shares with the buttons. I tried experimenting with the QuickPoll.view.id to get the actual id of the instance itself, but then I ran into the issue of the fact that when a button is pressed, it creates a brand new interaction id.

Any advice as to how to approach this problem would be much appreciated. Also feel free to (kindly please) critique my code (or even my question) if there is a better way to approach all of what I've done so far

Comment: Why do you have a command _inside_ of a view, and why are both your Views also a Cog???? Cogs and Views are two completely different things... And the reason all polls are interacting with each other is because you're storing all of it inside of the same View instance. This is just how OOP works.

Comment: so 1 cog for the quickpoll command, and regular class files for the timer, nomorebuttons, and 2buttons classes? how can i access the view from a different class in this case, so that I can edit the embeded message (or the react_message)?

Comment: Yes, your view should be a different class, and the data should either be kept in the view (if it shouldn't persist) or in a database (if it should). If you want to access something from within another class, you pass that data in the `__init__` (if available, otherwise set it as an attribute). This is also just OOP.

Comment: @stijndcl Thanks, that makes sense. Last thing: I'm not sure how to handle the some_callback callback from the Timer, because I use it to edit the react_message in order to show the remaining time. Any advice for that?

Comment: What's the problem with it exactly? What are you not sure about?

Comment: @stijndcl in the some_callback callback, i need a way to edit the react_message which contains the view. But apart from putting the react_message into an attribute (which i think contributed to my problem in the first place?), i'm not sure how to access it from the Timer class if that makes sense

Comment: Why can you not just do the same as above & pass anything you need into the `__init__` when you create the Timer instance? Every `QuickPoll.<X>` in the original code is wrong in every way & should be removed (you you need an instance of the class instead of just using the name). Also - something random I just noticed - instead of creating a new view (`NoMoreButtons`), just use the `clear_items` method from the original view to clear it & update the message with _that_.

Comment: @stijndcl ah i see now, so the original problem was that i had the view instantiation as an attribute inside its own class, creating a new one each time it was called. but now that i separated the classes out, i can pass the view into the timer class. thanks so much for the help! i learned a lot. will edit my post once i get it working

Comment: Yes, but even if it's an attribute you still can't access it without it being an instance, you can only get the default (static) value assigned to it. If you update it in the View (like you did when adding poll info) this won't be visible when using the class name, so something like `QuickPoll.view` will always be `None`. The data from one instance isn't visible statically.

Comment: is this what youre saying: when an object is instantiated in Class1, any updates to it's attributes are all contained within that class instance, so another class(i.e. Class2) can only have access to the default values?

Comment: If you create an instance of an object, anything that happens inside of it only happens in that instance & doesn't affect other instances. For example, you can have a `Counter()` class with a value, and two separate `Counter`s will have to different values at the same time. You can only access those values by the specific instances, i.e. saying which specific counter you want to get the value of. Just like in `discord.py`, everything inside of `guild.members` is a `discord.Member` instance, but all of them have different ids and names.

Comment: Sorry just repeating the basics: so in my case, when i run "view = QuickPollButtons()", if i only want to access that specific instantiation, i can only use the "view" variable and cannot reference QuickPollButtons() again unless I want to create a whole new object, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'd recommend you to read up on OOP somewhere because it'll make developing your bot a lot easier. It's a fundamental concept that the entirety of the `discord.py` library is built with.